# Angular Templating Inside Script Tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to force Angular to recognize an expression with a variable inside a script tag? For reasons beyond my control, this is sort of how I have to run things.

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="testvar" />
  <input type="button" onclick="clickFn()" value="Test" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.clickFn = function() {
        console.log('{{testvar}}');
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

with just a basic app invocation

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
```

Basically I want to be able to utilize an angular variable within a basic function that's not bound to the app, even though the script tag that calls the function is housed within the app. I know this is not the best of practices, but I think it's the only solution for my problem. Any other solutions are also welcome. Thanks!

**[Fiddle for playing](https://jsfiddle.net/8kpfu42w/)**

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning why you have this restriction. Who's calling `window.clickFn`? You can't ask us to do something that you know to be a bad pattern and not give a detailed explanation. You could just do `window.clickFn = e =>console.log($scope.testvar)` from the controller constructor

Comment: @juan the function is called on the button click. My restriction comes from multiple levels of content authorability. In one section an author will be able to put a templates variable, like {{testvar}} and in another location, input the value for testvar. These get rendered to the page with Java, which is the reason for the inline script tag.

Comment: Please don't explain it to me only. Improve your question by adding the information I suggested. Also, did you try the suggestion I made?

Answer (score 0):

If we are going to hell, why not do it in style?

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="testvar" />
  <input type="button" onclick="clickFn()" value="Test" />
  <p id="testvar" style="display:none">
  {{testvar}}
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.clickFn = function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("testvar").innerHTML);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Bind that variable to the DOM, and then shamelessly read in the `textContent` or `innerHTML` depending on target browser.

Here is your fiddle back: https://jsfiddle.net/8kpfu42w/2/